# Generating a PDF with two parallel tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I am attempting to dynamically generate a PDF using iTextSharp with a SQL table of phone book data. My program can currently generate a table with all of the wanted data.
[image: Table of phone book data]

Each page of the PDF only has one long table running down the middle though. I am attempting to format the PDF to have two tables running parallel down the page. When the table reaches the bottom of the page I want the next PdfPRow to be the top of the next table. This is my current C# code to attempt this. [image: This is my current C# code to attempt this.]

I break up my table into an array of PdfPRows. I then iterate through these adding each row to a new table called section. When the amount of rows have been added that I want I then nest the section table one of two cells on the final table. When I attempt to add this final table to the PDF it throws this error:

> iTextSharp.text.DocumentException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.Add(IElement
>   element) at iTextSharp.text.Document.Add(IElement element) at
>   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\Inetpub\wwwroot\app\cts\phonebook\DefaultPDF.aspx.cs:line 211

I take this to mean that some part of the final table was never initialized but I am not sure. The section after the first for loop is me attempting to fix this error. It is probably not necessary.

Is there is a better way to do this or I am just doing it wrong?

Comment: Can you post your relevant code that's generating the tables?

Comment: There can never be a reason for using the `PdfPRow` class. It's an internal class; keep it internal. You are using an old version of iText (we don't call it iTextSharp anymore). What you are trying to achieve is much simpler using the latest version: iText 7.1.2. So please upgrade if you want to make progress with your code and be future-proof.

Comment: One of the things you are doing wrong: posting code as screenshot. You should always post code as code. Another thing you are doing wrong: not mentioning the version of iText you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the images provided, this is what I would attempt to do as a start.

First, a couple of knowns.

1. The data in 2 columns does not exceed 1 page.  If it does, this gets more complicated.
2. Pdf table writes the cells across and then down.  With a table of 3 columns, it will write the first 3 cells in the first row and then write the 4th cell in the 2 row

I would set the final table up with 7 colmuns, 6 with data and 1 as a spacer between the 2 data sets.  I would then split the rows into 2 arrays.  You will need to handle the case of an odd number.  Then I would add each row cell by cell, taking the first row from each list to write the first data row of the table.

```
  PdfPTable FinalTableN = new PdfPTable( 7 );
  PdfPRow[] n = PDFtableN.Rows.ToArray();

  int half = n.Length/2;
  PdfPRow[] s1 = new PdfPRow[half];
  PdfPRow[] s2 = new PdfPRow[half];

  for (int h = 0; h < half; h++ )
    s1[h] = n[h];
  for ( int h = half; h < n.Length; h++ )
    s2[h-half] = n[h];

  for ( int h = 0; h < half; h++ ) {
    FinalTableN.AddCell( s1[h].GetCells()[0] );
    FinalTableN.AddCell( s1[h].GetCells()[1] );
    FinalTableN.AddCell( s1[h].GetCells()[2] );
    FinalTableN.AddCell( "" );
    FinalTableN.AddCell( s2[h].GetCells()[0] );
    FinalTableN.AddCell( s2[h].GetCells()[1] );
    FinalTableN.AddCell( s2[h].GetCells()[2] );
  }
```

You can control the width of the columns by supplying a float[7] of values to the PdfPTable constructor instead of the the number of columns